# C# define that a class instance can never be null (it only contains no data)

Tags: c#, class, instance

Out of curiosity: Is there a way to create a class whose reference to the class instance can never be set to null?
Like haveing only a readonly pointer that can only be set to null by the class itself.

What I have in mind:
I would want to have an easy to read /use object that either exists with data or exists without (shown by an attribute like *hasData = false*). It is always accessable and should never be null / point to nowhere which as a side effect gets also rid of NullReferenceExceptions for objects that are sometimes supposed to not have a value without the need of checking for null.

Comment: You could always set hasData to false in the constructor.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking. So basically, you want a static class that cannot be set to null?

Comment: Since the constructor dosn't need to be run, I guess: No.  This : `yourClass  anInstance = null;` can't be avoided, can it?

Comment: @RickRunowski: how?

Comment: A class is never null - a reference to an instance may be null. The design question is: Who creates the instance? You could make it return an Option<'T> instead of a 'T. Then users cannot ignore the fact that sometimes there is None...

Comment: Having an empty object and a null object seems equivalent to me. All it changes is notation.

Comment: @VolkerSchmidt Having a series of assembler instructions appears to be equivalent to have some high level language source which eventually will produce those assembler instructions... It is about being able to express if the value shall be never null or expected to be null. Depending on how the reference was initialized, this is relevant semantics. Semantics, expressable by the chosen type.

Comment: C# code to assembler code is a one-to-many mapping, so I don't see how that is an equivalence. For the problem at hand however, I see no difference between using a non-nullable type and using value??Default. Well, of course structs and classes have differences, but those don't seem relevant to the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature does not exists (yet). There is big discussion of non-nullable reference types at Roslyn forum: [non-nullable reference types (the one billion $ mistake)](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/541334). But currently you cannot restrict *reference type* variable from assigning `null` value.

You can use *value type* (struct) instead, but it's not stored in heap, passed by value etc.

All other options will not guarantee that someone will not assign `null` to variable of your reference type. But you still can use something like [Null Object](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/null_object) pattern to simplify your life (processing objects without data in same way as usual objects).

Comment: thank you for this - this is what I was looking for, interesting lecture!

Answer (score 3):

In such a case, you may want to use a struct instead of a class. Class is a reference type and therefore its default value is null, hence a variable containing an instance can be nulled (assigned null). There is no way to prevent it. On the other hand, struct is a value type and default for struct is an empty struct - i.e. a struct whose members are set to their defaults (0 for an int field, null for a field of a reference type etc.)

**Example of a struct**

```
public struct Foo
{
    public int Bar;
}
```

**And its usage (notice it is not instantiated but still it is NOT null)**

```
Foo foo;
foo.Bar = 1;
```

More about structs can be found here on the [MSDN sites](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saxz13w4.aspx).

Comment: good example +1 although I marked another post as the answer since there are no non-nullable reference types yet but this is working, thx

Answer (score 2):

As Anton mentioned, you could use a struct which cannot have a default value of null. But I am thinking you want something more like this:

```
public class DataObject
{
    public static bool HasData
    {
        get
        {
            return myObject != null;
        }
    }

    public static DataObject PresistentDataObject
    {
        get
        {
            return myObject;
        }
    }

    static DataObject myObject = new DataObject();
}
```

This code seems like bad practice. And maybe you'd want to resort to something like dependency injection with a singleton which will avoid setting up a state class like this.

Comment: thank you, unless there`s a non-nullable reference type this comes very close!

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the motivation behind such a question drives the qualities/properties of a solution.

Here, I suppose, the motivation is to avoid runtime exceptions of (faulty) code which tries to access a null reference as if it held an instance.

```
class Foo<T> {
    T data; // might be null or hold an instance...
    Foo<T>() {
        data = GetInstanceOfTInMysteriousWays(); // might return null...
    }
    bool DoSomething() {
       return data.Value > 5; // might throw an exception...
    }
    // ... more members...
}
```

To prevent this type of errors, you could borrow from C#'s cousin language F#.
If the function `T GetInstanceOfTInMysteriousWays<T>()` by design and contract is permitted to either return an instance or a null value, a better design of that function would be to have it return not T but an `Option<T>`. Then, the type of `Foo.data` would not be `T` but `Option<T>` and the user code in `DoSomething()` could not simply access member `data.Value`. Thus, this common pattern of bugs would be eliminated.

```
// Improved code from above
class Foo<T> {
    Option<T> data; // Option is a struct type and cannot be null...
    Foo<T>() {
        data = GetInstanceOfTInMysteriousWays();
    }
    bool DoSomething() {
         if (data.IsSome() ) {
             return data.TryGetValue().Value > 5; 
         }
         return false;
    }
}
```

Now the only question is, where to find that Option type in C#? There are several github projects creating such a type (google is your friend). You could also consider to link the F# core library and use the Option type defined there, maybe along with a little helper as is shown in [this gist snippet](http://www.fssnip.net/so).

Comment: Option<T> is the type I was looking for but it doen`t exist (yet), I will have a look at F# and the Github projects - great information

Answer (score 0):

If your class is named foo, then you would have at least one constructor (possibly more).  In that constructor you would assign the variable to false.

```
public foo(){
    hasData = false;
}
```

As @Anton points out, this only works if the variable is instansiated.
    foo f = new foo();

it would still be null if you assigned it as null:
    foo f = null;

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure, I understand the question correctly or not. Let me add
>   some points here:

Hope that you misunderstand the term `Instance`, If you create an instance of the class then it will not be `null`, Let `myClass` be a class that you have created already. You are not creating any instance of the class by using `myClass myClassObject`. The `myClassObject` will became an instance of the class only when an instance of the class is assigned to it, Until then it is `null` which means not existing.

Comment: yes, my explanation was a bit unaccurate when it comes to instances.. you are right, I just want to never have the declarated object being null / pointing to nothing

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you'd need a `struct` for that.

**However, we can tackle this from a different angle (in a class):**

Since the *variable* can point to null, let's define the variable in a way that it can't be set to null:

```
private Class1 _c = new Class1();
public Class1 c { get { return _c; } set { if (value != null) _c = value; } }
```

so `c` will not be set to `null`.

---

A `struct` per your requirements:

```
struct Struct1
{
    public bool hasData { get { return Data != null; } }
    public Class1 Data;
}
```